# VS Code with Julia Extension never completes

Tags: visual-studio-code, julia

I'm running on Windows 10:

```
Processor   Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-10900K CPU @ 3.70GHz   3.70 GHz
Installed RAM   64.0 GB (63.8 GB usable) Device
ID  A90B50D3-489B-4AE1-BB44-38804085FE3A Product
ID  00330-53385-62923-AAOEM System type 64-bit operating system,
x64-based processor
```

I have installed and tested Julia:

[image]

I downloaded the latest version of VS Code and tried my "Hello World" Julia script as follows:

[image]

As you can see a the bottom of the screen, it never runs the program.
It is stuck!

Any help or suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Charles

Comment: Ctrl + shft + enter will run the file in the REPL (not in the debugger). Does that work?

Comment: When I pull down the Run menu of VS Code, it shows "Run Without Debugging".  I choose this, and it did not make any difference.  I did not understand: "Ctrl; + shift " enter".  As I have shown above, Julia runs my script o.k.

Comment: If you click the play button at the top right, it will execute the file in the REPL. You will see a terminal open at the bottom of vscode and print the message. Don’t use the Run menu in the top toolbar of vscode.

Comment: At the bottom of the screen is says: 0 <triangle> 0 Launch Program (Julia) Julia env: [Loading] Starting Julia Language Server..., and the it hangs. No further output.

Comment: No idea what is going on on your end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like many people seem to have this issue, but the VS Code devs claim the bug has been fixed. Is it possible you are using an old version of the Julia VS Code Extension? See this issue: https://github.com/julia-vscode/julia-vscode/issues/1780 for details.

I was able to replicate some similar behavior (albeit on a different OS) and filed an issue here: https://github.com/julia-vscode/julia-vscode/issues/2391

I suggest you do the same unless any of the fixes on the first issue linked above work for you.

Comment: I uninstalled Julia extension v1.3.30 and installed Julia Insider v1.3.32.  This did not fix the problem. No Cigar!

Comment: Make sure to open an issue then on the repo.

Comment: I uninstalled VS Code and  Julia extension v1.3.30. I then re-installed VS Code and installed Julia Insider v1.3.33.  This release fixed the problem.  I'm now up-and-running.  Thanks guys!